# TypeError: string object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm getting this `TypeError` on the `print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.")`, on line 4. I've tried f-strings and even `str(ageStr) / str(age)` - I'm still getting same error on line 4.

```
ageStr = "24" #I'm 24 years old.
age = int(ageStr)

print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.")
three = "3"

answerYears = age + int(three)

print("The total number of years:" + "answerYears")
answerMonths = answerYears*12 

print("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + answerMonths + " months old"
```

Comment: What have you stored in `print`? Can't ask you what is the output of `print(print)` also.

Comment: Your code by itself does not exhibit the error. Somewhere in your code *not shown*, you have assigned a string to ``print``, e.g. ``print = "24"``. Note that once you fix this, the last line will throw an error since you cannot concatenate strings and integers - use ``str(answerMonths)`` instead.

Comment: I think you have not put the closing bracket after print in line 11 ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly store a number in it's string type and integer type in different variables. You can simply convert an integer into string object by `str(integer)` and a string object to integer object using `int(string)`

Comment: what about line 4 - print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.") ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your error,

```
print("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + str(answerMonths) + " months old")
```

Second solution is simply remove string concatenation,

```
print("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be ", answerMonths, " months old")
```

Comment: That is a different error than the question is about.

Comment: Does not help OP.

Comment: what about line 4 - print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.") ?

Comment: ageStr is of str type, hence no need of typecasting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicilty type cast int variable into str when you want to print:

```
ageStr = "24" #I'm 24 years old.
age = int(ageStr)

print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.")
three = "3"

answerYears = age + int(three)

print("The total number of years:" + str(answerYears))
answerMonths = answerYears*12 

print("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + str(answerMonths) + " months old")
```

Ouput:

```
I'm 24years old.                                                                                                      
The total number of years:27                                                                                          
In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be 324 months old
```

Comment: That is a different error than the question is about.

Comment: Does not help OP.

Comment: what about line 4 - print("I'm "+ ageStr +"years old.") ?

Comment: @Masi ageStr is already of str type so no need to typecast it